# Windows Server 2012 Inplace upgrade fails

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Attempting inplace upgrade of Windows Server 2012 (x64) to R2 (x64)

Server is virtual (vmware)
ISO downloaded from VLSC

Login to Windows run setup.exe

Installer quits with the following error (at the end of the first phase of the install):

***[Setup cannot continue due to a corrupted installation file. Contact the vendor of your Windows installation disc or your system administrator for assistance.]***

I've tried this with a new install of 2012 and upgrade to R2 with the same media -> no issues

Installed straight 2012R2 with no issues as well from the same iso.

Tried mounting the iso in Windows -> same error

Extracted iso -> same error

I've also tried both getting updates and not getting updates for Windows Setup.

Not sure where to go from here. Any help / suggestions would be great.

Logs:
Setupact.log

> 2013-11-27 11:11:53, Info                  IBS
>   ValidateOfflineImage: dism.exe returned with exit code [0x800F0830].
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:53, Error      [0x0606fd] IBS
>   ValidateOfflineImage: dism.exe returned with failing exit code
>   [0x800F0830]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:53, Error      [0x0606f5] IBS
>   ValidateOfflineImage: An error occurred while validating
>   serviceability of offline image. Error code is [0x800F0830]
>
> 2013-11-27
>   11:11:53, Info       [0x0640ae] IBSLIB PublishMessage: Publishing
>   message [Setup cannot continue due to a corrupted installation file.
>   Contact the vendor of your Windows installation disc or your system
>   administrator for assistance. ]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:53, Info
>   [0x0a013d] UI     Accepting Cancel. Exiting Page Progress.

Setuperr.log

> 2013-11-27 11:00:57, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin
>   {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: LoadLibrary error
>   (C:\Windows\system32\TableTextServiceMig.dll) gle=0
>
> 2013-11-27
>   11:03:05, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin
>   {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG:
>   CBrgUnattend::CollectBridgeSettings failed: 0x1, 0
>
> 2013-11-27
>   11:03:22, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin
>   {D12A3141-A1FF-4DAD-BF67-1B664DE1CBD6}: WSLicensing: Failed to read
>   machine binding, hr=0x80070002
>
> 2013-11-27 11:03:22, Error
>   [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {D12A3141-A1FF-4DAD-BF67-1B664DE1CBD6}:
>   WSLicensing: Error reading Server Info hr=0x80070490
>
> 2013-11-27
>   11:11:22, Error                 CSI    0000012f (F) Component marked
>   deleted and is no longer available for:
>   [ml:280{140},l:138{69}]"amd64_sdbus.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_62a11cce9e4e184e"[gle=0x80004005]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:22, Error                 CSI    00000130 (F)
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(50) #1246815# from
>   Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSIStore_ICSIStore::GetComponentInformation(flags
>   = 0, class = (unknown enumerant 2), information = [24]"[gle=0x80070032]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:22, Error                 CBS
>   Doqe: Failed processing queue [HRESULT = 0x80070032 -
>   ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:22, Error                 CBS
>   Doqe: Failed while processing driver operations queue. [HRESULT =
>   0x80070032 - ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:22, Error
>   CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80070032
>   - ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:22, Error                 CBS    Failed to perform operation.  [HRESULT = 0x80070032 -
>   ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:23, Error                 MIG
>   OC::COCDismAdapter::EnableDisableOCs: Image is not serviceable; cannot
>   proceed.[gle=0x0000007a]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:23, Error
>   MIG    OC::CInstalledOCStore::ModifyOCsState: Failed to enable and
>   disable OCs; hr = 0x800F0830[gle=0x0000007a]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:23,
>   Error                 MIG    Failed to restore OC status; HRESULT =
>   0x800F0830[gle=0x0000007a]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:24, Error
>   MIG    OC Exception:  [0x00000830]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:24, Error
>   [0x080717] MIG    pUpgradeInstallOC: Failed to restore OC status.
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:53, Error      [0x0606fd] IBS
>   ValidateOfflineImage: dism.exe returned with failing exit code
>   [0x800F0830]
>
> 2013-11-27 11:11:53, Error      [0x0606f5] IBS
>   ValidateOfflineImage: An error occurred while validating
>   serviceability of offline image. Error code is [0x800F0830]

Comment: Have you tried to [repair your system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824869.aspx) yet?

Comment: Yes, passed all with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Windows Server 2012 R2 media released on December 11, 2013 fixes this.

In place upgrade no longer fails. Upgrade successful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your current Windows Server 2012 installation is corrupted. The error 0x800F0830 means the following:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x800F0830
# for hex 0x800f0830 / decimal -2146498512
  CBS_E_IMAGE_UNSERVICEABLE                                      cbsapi.h
# The image has been damaged by an offline servicing failure
# and no further servicing is allowed
# 1 matches found for "0x800F0830"
```

You must do a clean install, the upgrade is blocked.

Comment: What tool did you use to determine that? Thanks.

Comment: I've used the tool `err.exe` from the Windows 7 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue to this and I wanted to share our experience with others, I'm sure it could help someone else if not the original poster (see specifically deleting the registry key step to help you with

> CBS_E_IMAGE_UNSERVICEABLE, error 0x800F0830).

We originally got into this situation installing windows updates, it failed tried to revert changes and boot looped. We eventually managed to repair the system with the DISM command in command prompt under Windows repair (booting from disk).

However the windows updates would all fail afterwards but we could at least boot  to the desktop!

We ran `sfc /scannow` which said it detected issues and fixed them, but we still had windows update errors every time, we then ran the following dism command using the latest iso (obtained as a trial):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:E:\Sources\Install.wim:2 /LimitAccess
```

Note we used `LimitAccess` (to bypass WSUS) and install wim2 (not wim1) was defined as apparently wim1 was for CORE installation, which we weren't using.

We received the error below:

> DISM (Error 0x800f081f) and SFC (Failed to Repair)

Found this also in the CBS log (C:\Windows\Logs\CBS):

> "Error CBS The image has been damaged by an offline servicing failure and no further servicing is allowed. [HRESULT = 0x800f0830 - CBS_E_IMAGE_UNSERVICEABLE]"

Please perform at your own risk.
Delete the following registry key that is blocking the command (you may have to change owner in permissions to delete it).

> "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing" Delete attribute "Unserviceable"

Then re-run the DISM command preferably with the very latest image file or online (again as I mentioned before we had to use an official downloaded trial ISO, because our WSUS server seemed to stop the online DISM command working). We didn't use the original installation disk because our system had been patched to a higher level in windows update.

We then experienced no CBS errors.
Hopefully this would allow your update process as well.

Also to add, this was the failing update specifically: KB3013767